# What is the value of $c$ in this problem of sequence and series?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$a,b,c$  is in A.P. and $a^2,b^2,c^2$ is in G.P.If $a<b<c$ & $a + b + c = \dfrac {3}{2}$ ,what is the value of $c$?[When I wanted to do it,I found $a + d = \dfrac {1}{2}$,$d$ being the common difference,say.Thus $b$ = $\dfrac{1}{2}$  . Now I get $a + c = 1$.As $a^2,b^2,c^2$ is in G.P. we get $b$ =$\sqrt{ac}$ 
& finally get $a = c$ But it will be a contradiction.]

Comment: Any problem that requires solving equations could be written as "what is the value of c?" so your title isn't going to attract people who have specific interest in the area you're asking about. I thought it was going to be a question about the speed of light. So how about mentioning arithmetic and geometric progressions in your title?

Comment: Thnks,for finding the flaw.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that the geometric progression is in the squares of $a,b,c$ so that you have $a^2c^2=b^4$ whence $ac=\pm b^2$

You have $a+c=1$ from the AP condition and $ac=\pm b^2=\pm\frac 14$ from the GP condition. With the positive sign we know that $a,c$ are roots of the quadratic $$x^2-x+\frac 14=\left(x-\frac 12\right)^2=0$$Which is the case you have considered. But with the negative sign:$$x^2-x-\frac 14=0=\left(x-\frac 12\right)^2-\frac 12$$ and $x=\cfrac {1\pm \sqrt 2}{2}$ giving the arithmetic progression $$\frac {1- \sqrt 2}2,\frac 12, \frac {1+ \sqrt 2}2$$ with common difference $\cfrac {\sqrt 2}2$ and the geometric progression $$\frac {3-2\sqrt 2}4, \frac 14, \frac {3+2\sqrt 2}4$$ with common ratio $3+2\sqrt 2$